# Remove the entirety of git using powershell, Windows 10

Tags: git, windows-10

So I have accidentally added git tracking to my entire desktop. Could you help  me by finding a solution, on how to remove it from my desktop, unfortunately this error pops.

```
`PS C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop> rmdir .git
```

rmdir : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop.git' because it does not exist.`

> Is it hidden? If so how do I find it?

Answer (score 1):

To find the root directory of your git repo :

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

Then, try deleting the absolute path : `<root_dir>\.git`